# Binding on background color with a custom style on a button and checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am currently working on a WPF application and have redefined the buttons and checkbox to use a custom style in App.xaml.

**App.xaml**

```xml
<Style x:Key="{x:Type CheckBox}" TargetType="CheckBox">
  <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,10,5" />
  <Setter Property="Width" Value="85" />
  <Setter Property="Height" Value="50" />
  <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
  <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
    Value="{DynamicResource CheckBoxFocusVisual}" />
  <Setter Property="Template" />
  <Setter.Value />
  <!-- ... etc. -->
</Style>
```

The code is from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752319%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with some modifications.

Now I want to change the background color through coding. For example, if the title of the checkbox is "a" then the background color would be red and so on. I succeeded in binding the titles but not the background color. My checkboxes are used inside a control item.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Grid>
  <ItemsControl Name="ControllerDisplay">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding controltitle}"
            Style="{StaticResource MainControltitle}"/>
          <CheckBox>
            // want to change checkbox background
            <CheckBox.Style>
              <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}"
                BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type CheckBox}}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Aqua" />
              </Style>
            </CheckBox.Style>
            <StackPanel >
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding controlno}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                FontSize="16" />
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding status}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                FontSize="10"/>
            </StackPanel>
          </CheckBox>
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>                    
  </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

**on the coding side:**

```cs
public void printcheckbox()
{         
    List<Controller> listItem = new List<Controller>();

    listItem.Add(new Controller() { controltitle = "title1", controlno = "12345",
        status = "On" , controlbg = Colors.Red});

    ControllerDisplay.ItemsSource = listItem;
}

public class Controller
{
    public string controltitle { get; set; }
    public string controlno { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public Color controlbg { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean you want to binding background color to stackpanel in DataTemplate? If so, you should use Brush in Controller object or SolidColorBrush in xaml.

Comment: Nope, I would like to change the whole checkbox background color. I used a stackpanel + textblock just to display two rows of text inside the checkbox. Thanks!

Comment: Bind the text property of textblock to Checkbox background property. By using a converter convert it to Red (SolidColorBrush) if the object value is "a".

Comment: If you bind the title to CheckBox Content property you can simply use Style.Triggers to achieve this.

Comment: @VictoryJessie Yes! Didn't thought of that! Let me try first.

Comment: @user1702061 my suggestion helped or not?